# Firebase Realtime database read with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm currently working on a project that displays Arduino weight data on a app, the data goes through Firebase to the app. And I now wanted to make a simple app that just displays a number (like a hello world) but I cant figure it out on how to do it with flutter (this is what I made with js https://prnt.sc/p7frdz)

Comment: Do you need create a project that read a document in a firebase e show result on the app?

Comment: yes, exactly that. Just plain text

Comment: I do not know your question, if you already know how to set up an application in firebase and if you need help only with flutter, but I believe that this video can help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqJ_KjFzL9I

If you after watching the video still fail I can try to help you with a sample code but it is not so the code needs some settings in the console of the firebase.